# How to get Silverlight or XAML for Windows Compact 2013 for C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-ce, smart-device

I'm writing an application on a Windows Compact 2013 device and wish to use Silverlight to get rich UI elements. The Silverlight forms created from Expression Blend can only be used with C++ and not C#.

Is it possible to do this with C#, or are there any other alternatives to Silverlight for a good-looking UI?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually adding an empty row between controls, i.e.: `Grid.Row="0`" for `Label` and `Grid.Row="2"`  for `Button`. It should be in sequential order like shown below::

```
    <Label x:Name="Screen"
           Text=""
           Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
           FontSize="50"
           TextColor="Black"
           BackgroundColor="White"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
           VerticalTextAlignment="End"/>

    <Button x:Name="Button1"
            Text="1"
            FontSize="40"
            TextColor="White"
            BackgroundColor="Aquamarine"
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            Clicked="Button1_Clicked"/>
```

I would also recommend for the task of making a calculator (like the working app at http://www.shopdigit.com/Engineering-Calculator-VOLTA-814-R814-0-03.htm) use the separate resource file and make sure to set the properties

```
<ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

You can also use '`center`' property like in sample actual implementation:

```
<!--TEXT BLOCK-->
<Style x:Key="TextBlock_Generic">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="14" />
</Style>
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: I've not included the entire code here. In a later part, I'm using this row. I'm actually make a calculator and the '+', '-', '*' and '/' go into row 1 and the numbers 1,2,3... start from row 2 onwards.

Comment: Read my extended answer. Also, it would be better if you include that entire code snippet, otherwise it's hard to reproduce the issue. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll upload the entire code asap and try this as well.